# Why is VueJS throwing a prop mutation warning when prop value does not change?

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I've created a small test component.  Whenever I type into the input, VueJS tells me I am mutating the 'value' prop event though I am not.  Can someone tell me what is going on here?

```
<template>
    <input type="text" :value="propValue" @input="inputHandler">
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            propValue : this.value
        };
    },
    props : [
        'value'
    ],
    methods : {
        inputHandler(event) {
            this.$emit('input', event.target.value);
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

I do notice in the console that I get two "You are running Vue in development mode." messages.  Does that mean I have VueJS being called twice?  Will that cause the error above to happen?

**SOLVED:** The issue was indeed two copies of VueJS being included in the bundle.  I switched the `vue$` resolve.alias path to point to an absolute path rather than relative and it fixed it.

```
resolve : {
    alias : {
        'vue$' : path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js')
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't really need your `propValue` data property. You can safely use `:value="value"`

Comment: I also suggest using `propValue` for your `v-model` on your `input` and then changing `event.target.value` to `this.propValue` in your `inputHandler()`

Comment: @Derek my guess is OP is creating a [custom component](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events)

Comment: @Phil ahhh, fair enough

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue: https://jsfiddle.net/kjbsy52u/

Comment: Thanks for your input everyone.

Turns out the issue was that Webpack was including two copies of VueJS into the bundle and it was making VueJS go crazy.